# yum install fails with key error

Tags: redhat, yum, rpm

This install fails:

```
 yum install osad
...
warning:
/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/spacewalk-client/packages/osad- 5.11.57-1.el7.noarch.rpm: 
Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 066e5810: NOKEY

Public key for osad-5.11.57-1.el7.noarch.rpm is not installed
```

Yet, the key for the spacewalk repo is install.

```
[root@swtest rpm-gpg]# rpm -q --info gpg-pubkey-b8002de1-553126bd
Name        : gpg-pubkey
Version     : b8002de1
Release     : 553126bd
Architecture: (none)
Install Date: Mon 09 Nov 2015 10:31:03 AM EST
Group       : Public Keys
Size        : 0
License     : pubkey
Signature   : (none)
Source RPM  : (none)
Build Date  : Fri 17 Apr 2015 11:29:01 AM EDT
Build Host  : localhost
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : Spacewalk <spacewalk-devel@redhat.com>
```

What is causing the error, and other than --nogpgcheck, how can I fix it?

Update: Client Centos 7. Using spacewalk 2.3 with no troubles until this.

Comment: Which Red Hat version are you using?  Did you follow the instructions at https://fedorahosted.org/spacewalk/wiki/HowToInstall for "Setting up Spacewalk repo"?

Comment: Did you try yum clean all to clear the cache?

Comment: I tried yum clean all, but the problem persists.